How to calculate the weighted standard deviation for an overall score with different contributions?"
For our course : there was a quiz of 15 marks , final of 30 marks. The final exam consisted of two papers of 15 marks. if q are marks in quiz and f1 are marks in final paper 1 and f2 are marks in final paper 2, then the final score is (q/15)*40 +((f1+f2)/30)*60.  here are some of the stats- paper 1 of final:                                                    Minimum: 0.0
Maximum: 15.0
Mean: 6.02
Median: 6.0
Standard Deviation: 3.6                                                                                         paper 2 of final:                                                                                               Minimum: 0.0
Maximum: 15.0
Mean: 5.1
Median: 5.0
Standard Deviation: 3.66                                                                                   Quiz :                                                                                                             Minimum: 0.0
Maximum: 15.0
Mean: 4.77
Median: 4.0
Standard Deviation: 3.5
I have calculated the overall mean to be 34.96 and median to be 32.67. how can i find the standard deviation of this dataset. The sample size is same for all.
